# Read tab delimited text file in Spark R

Tags: r, apache-spark, tabs, sparkr, txt

I have a tab delimited file that is saved as a .txt with " " around the string variables. The file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmdt12ivfzd8ebb/FILE.TXT?dl=0).

I am trying to read it into Spark-R (version 3.1.2), but cannot successfully bring it into the environment. I've tried variations of the `read.df` code, like this:

`df <- read.df(path = "FILE.txt", header="True", inferSchema="True", delimiter = "\t", encoding="ISO-8859-15")`

`df <- read.df(path = "FILE.txt", source = "txt", header="True", inferSchema="True", delimiter = "\t", encoding="ISO-8859-15")`

I have had success with bringing in CSVs with `read.csv`, but many of the files I have are over 10GB, and is not practical to convert them to CSV before bring them into Spark-R.

EDIT: When I run `read.df` I get a laundry list of errors, starting with this:

[image]

I am able to bring in csv files used in a previous project with both `read.df` and `read.csv`, so I don't think it's a java issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to specifically use Spark R, then base R `read.table` should work just fine for the .txt you provided. Note that it is tab-delimited, and so this should be specified.

Something like this should work:

```
dat <- read.table("FILE.TXT",  
                  sep="\t",
                  header=TRUE)
```

Comment: It does not. I was hoping the link to the .txt file would be helpful. Is there anything I can do to make it clearer?

Comment: See update, I think you can easily solve this with read.table if you don't need to specifically use R-Spark.

Comment: Note that the above avoids the read-in error you shared and then you can of course feed the dat object into R-Spark as a df, but if the issue is loading it into memory, then this does not help.

Comment: Thanks! The issue is that a few of my files are absolutely massive - around 15GB or so. I thought that SparkR would be the best way to bring them in since running ```read.table``` never finishes. Is there a way for ```read.table``` to handle such large files?